Hi. I'm getting an error when using ADEGENET For Genetic Distance
I am trying to run genetic distance analysis using adegenet on RStudio and I keep getting an error that some individuals are missing the -5 SNPs. I've copied a section of the code and error below. Please help.
FST_pop <- read.PLINK("data1.raw", na.strings = c("0", "-9"), sep = "\t", select.subjects = NULL, select.snps = NULL, map.file = NULL, quiet = FALSE, chunkSize = 1000, parallel = require("parallel"), n.cores = 1)

Error in read.PLINK("umfazi.raw", na.strings = c("0", "-9"), sep = "\t",  : 
  some individuals do not have -5 SNPs.

I've tried to apply more and more stringent QC on PLINK to excleude animals with even 1% missing genotypes but I'm still getting the same error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It may not be the most ideal way to resolve this, but I was able to avoid that error by converting the tab separated .raw file produced by plink2  to match the space separated .raw file produced by older versions of plink.
I used the tr command, but I'm sure there are many better ways of doing this with awk, sed etc..
cat data1.raw | tr "\t" " " > space_data1.raw

Afterwards you can run read.plink in R as usual using the new file.
